# MS-Access IIF-statement combined with calculation

Tags: database, ms-access, comparison

I was wondering if someone could help me out with a bit of Microsoft Access. I am fairly new to the system, and I am trying to make a database system for my company. However, it does not seem to work.

The idea is, that when the checkbox `hoogtarief` is checked, the calculation will give a higher output.

The function will be used in price calculation, and hoog tarief means something like "high rate". We use a higher price for temporary clients. If the box is unchecked, the price-output should be like the second statement says.

```
IIF([hoogtarief]=-1, (([eindtijd]-[begintijd])*24)*12, (([eindtijd]-[begintijd])*24)*10)
```

Translated:

- `eindtijd`: stop time
- `begintijd`: starting time

The output prices are €12/h and €10/h, respective to the calculated time.

I hope you can help me out!

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is in a calculated column. There seem to be different coding principles in these columns, which I did not find yet.

Comment: Looks fine to me, except dates are in days, not hours. Please elaborate on _does not seem to work_

Comment: The thing is, I get a syntax error. The program seems to have some () or ! or commas where they shouldn't be, and I have been staring at this for a very long time, I just can't find the mistake... Thanks for the help with those days, I'll try to work that out.

Comment: Oh, you probably have Dutch language settings enabled, in which case the UI uses `;` as a separator instead of `,` (while SQL/VBA still uses comma's, poor design on Microsofts part). Try replacing all commas with semicolons.

Comment: I just rechecked the calculation parts individually, they seem to function as I want them to. They calculate the difference in time, multiply it by the given 10/12, and output the right price (double-checked those numbers with my calculator).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that! I'll try for a bit, I'll be right back!

Comment: Yay! It works as it should now! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Also, try the following: `([eindtijd]-[begintijd])*24*IIF([hoogtarief];12;10)` actually does exactly the same. Note the implicit cast to a boolean for that checkbox, since it's a yes/no field there's no need to check the value. It's more concise and more clear to me, as it's obvious that the only thing that changes is the multiplication factor.